# Flat tree vs Nested tree

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, tree, treeview

I'm creating a program wherein the user selects a single root directory. This root directory is then crawled, mapped, and stored in a JSON file. The JSON file will be fetched and displayed on the front-end at load to create an interactive tree. The user will be able to modify the tree via moving, renaming, adding, and deleting files and folders thereto.

**I've never done anything like this before, so I'm wondering whether it's more practical to store the tree in the JSON file as a one dimensional array or nested object?** The latter seems like it would be a lot more efficient, but a lot more complex. You would be able to delete whole branches much more easily, yet it would be a lot harder to access leafs. **Despite its complexity, would it be easier to work with? Or is there a different approach I'm unaware of?**

For whatever it's worth, I don't imagine users will be creating a super deep root directory.

Any input is appreciated.

## Flat

```
// files have a type, whereas folders have children

[
  {
    "parent": ,
    "path": ,
    "name": ,
    "children": [
      {
        "parent": ,
        "path": ,
        "name": ,
        "type":
      },
      {
        "parent": ,
        "path": ,
        "name": 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": ,
    "path": ,
    "name": ,
    "type":
  },
  {
    "parent": ,
    "path": ,
    "name": ,
    "children": []
  }
]
```

## Nested

```
// files have a type, whereas folders have children

{
  "parent": ,
  "path": ,
  "name": ,
  "children": [
    {
      "parent": ,
      "path": ,
      "name": ,
      "children": [
        {
          "parent": ,
          "path": ,
          "name": ,
          "children": [
            {
              "parent": ,
              "path": ,
              "name": ,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "parent": ,
              "path": ,
              "name": ,
              "type":
            },
            {
              "parent": ,
              "path": ,
              "name": ,
              "type":
            },
            {
              "parent": ,
              "path": ,
              "name": ,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parent": ,
      "path": ,
      "name": ,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```